# imagemagick: background stays white

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I tried to convert a pdf to an image:

```
convert -verbose
        -density 150
        -trim example.pdf
        -quality 100
        -background white
         output.png
```

Unfortunately it seems as if the presence of the background keyword has no influence on the output image because the final background stays transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You also need the "-flatten" option, to compose your transparent image against the white background.

By the way, don't use "-quality 100"; it doesn't mean what you think it does, when writing a PNG file.  95 would work better.

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
-background white -alpha remove
```

did the trick